# Where can I find example of 24 bit bitmap image RLE

Tags: c++, bitmap, image-compression

I understand that 24 bit bitmap image may not compress well using RLE. However, I written a digital circuit in VHDL that sends VGA signal to a display. In the testbench I want to write down the image data that shall then be converted to a bitmap file using a C program. Since each image is 800x600 in size, it is better if the the file is compressed and will reduce the file significantly. The bitmap format supports run length encoding compression.

(1)
I have looked for RLE examples. However, I can't find any for 24 bit bitmap image. Can you point out an example? Alternatively. Is there an application that will help me save a 24 bit bitmap file so I can use hex editor and learn how the format is saved?

(2)
Also, the only example of RLE used everywhere on the internet is below:

```
03 04 05 06 00 03 45 56 67 00 02 78 00 02 05 01
02 78 00 00 09 1E 00 01
```

This bitmap would expand as follows (two-digit values represent a color index for a single pixel):

```
04 04 04
06 06 06 06 06
45 56 67
78 78
move current position 5 right and 1 down
78 78
end of line
1E 1E 1E 1E 1E 1E 1E 1E 1E
end of RLE bitmap
```

Why does 45 56 67 only expand to the same thing?

OK, I understand how to write 24 bit RLE. I have written the program but the file generated by it is not being recognized by paint-it. I am not sure if the paint-it and other apps on my machine do not recognize 24 bit RLE bitmap or the bitmap file generated by my program is wrong. Thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

struct bitmap_file_header_struct {
    WORD    bfType;        // must be 'BM' 
    DWORD   bfSize;        // size of the whole .bmp file
    WORD    bfReserved1;   // must be 0
    WORD    bfReserved2;   // must be 0
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} bitmap_file_header;

struct bitmap_file_info_struct {
    DWORD  biSize;            // size of the structure
    LONG   biWidth;           // image width
    LONG   biHeight;          // image height
    WORD   biPlanes;          // bitplanes
    WORD   biBitCount;        // resolution 
    DWORD  biCompression;     // compression
    DWORD  biSizeImage;       // size of the image
    LONG   biXPelsPerMeter;   // pixels per meter X
    LONG   biYPelsPerMeter;   // pixels per meter Y
    DWORD  biClrUsed;         // colors used
    DWORD  biClrImportant;    // important colors
} bitmap_file_info;

#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    // image is 10 repeating pixels of value ff00ff followed by end of scaneline and end of rle
    unsigned char data[] = { 0x0A, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}; 

    bitmap_file_header.bfType = 0x4d42; // fixed for bitmap in windows
    bitmap_file_header.bfSize = sizeof(bitmap_file_header) + sizeof(bitmap_file_info) + sizeof(data); 
    bitmap_file_header.bfReserved1 = 0; // fixed 
    bitmap_file_header.bfReserved2 = 0; // fixed
    bitmap_file_header.bfOffBits = sizeof(bitmap_file_header) + sizeof(bitmap_file_info); //

    bitmap_file_info.biSize = sizeof(bitmap_file_info);
    bitmap_file_info.biWidth = 10;
    bitmap_file_info.biHeight = 1;
    bitmap_file_info.biPlanes = 1; // fixed
    bitmap_file_info.biBitCount = 24; // fixed for 24 bit image
    bitmap_file_info.biCompression = 4; // fixed, 4 used to set 24 bit run length encoding
    bitmap_file_info.biSizeImage = sizeof(data); // <-
    bitmap_file_info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0; // fixed
    bitmap_file_info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0; // fixed
    bitmap_file_info.biClrUsed = 0; // all colors used
    bitmap_file_info.biClrImportant = 0; // all colors are important

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("output.bmp", ios::out | ios::binary);
    myfile.write((const char *)&bitmap_file_header, sizeof(bitmap_file_header));
    myfile.write((const char *)&bitmap_file_info, sizeof(bitmap_file_info));
    myfile.write((const char *)&data, sizeof(data));
    myfile.close(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Use zlib, compress the bitmap, do whatever you want with it. Compress with zlib is lossless.

Comment: I shall look into zlib also. I first encountered rle which seems quite straight forward to do even in VHDL.

Comment: I have just now added the program code which is supposed to generate the 24 bit RLE image. I found how to do 24 bit RLE bitmap from "Digital Image Processing and Pattern Recognition" By Pakhira Malay K.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic form of RLE consists of pairs (or frames) of bytes of the form `<count> <value>`.  Clearly, in this form you would never have a `<count>` byte that is zero.

That allows the use of zero to act as a control code, signalling a different type of frame in the data.

Your particular example has been encoded using WMF (Windows Meta File) RLE format.  WMF allows for the following extra types of frame, all of which must be introduced using a `00` control code:

- `01` - end of data stream
- `02 <x> <y>` - relative move
- `03 <raw uncompressed data stream follows> 00` - raw uncompressed data follows that will be null terminated.

This explains why you would see `45 56 67` in the uncompressed output.

As to **why** the format uses this approach? RLE is inefficient for encoding data that does not repeat.  Consider `45 56 67`:

- the simple approach renders this as `01 45 01 56 01 67` (6 bytes);
- the extended approach results in `00 03 45 56 67 00` (also 6 bytes).

A better example would be if you needed to encode `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A`:

- this would require 20 bytes using basic frames;
- but 13 bytes using a `00 03 <data> 00` frame

Comment: The "absolute mode" as microsoft calls it is **not** null terminated. If the first byte is 00 and the second is greater than 2 (3-255) it will simply copy that many following bytes (or nibbles in case of RLE4). To ensure consistency the end is padded to a word boundary from the image data start, so it will stay in a 2 byte sequence. So "00 03 45 56 67 00" is read as copy the next 3 bytes to the output. Since there are 3 bytes (odd number) we need one padding byte. "00 06 12 32 15 17 81 91" This sequence will copy 6 bytes. Note there's **no padding byte** at the end.